# Mongooseim : mod_vcard crashing

Tags: ejabberd

I configured mod_vcard as follows:

```
{mod_vcard, [
        {allow_return_all, true},
        {search_all_hosts, true},
        {matches, 1},
        {search, true},
        {host, localhost},
        {backend, odbc}
      ]},
```

But when I restart mongoosIm i get the following error:

```
2015-03-16 12:31:08.620 [error] <0.708.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.708.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: bad argument in call to re:replace(localhost, "@HOST@", <<"localhost">>, [global,{return,binary}]) line 355 in mod_vcard:init/1 line 141 in gen_server:init_it/6 line 330
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try with latest version of ejabberd ? Latest version have Yaml config file and configuration checker. It should make it easier to find configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

The host parameter should be a string and not atom. Try this line:

```
{host, "localhost"},
```

Or any other host, depending on what you have in the **hosts** paramet